# How to delete all caches for previous bakes (particle system with hair dynamics enabled)

Tags: particles, hair, cache

I am a beginner to blender 2.8, and have played around in my current project a lot with hair particles, but at some point deleted all of them to start from scratch. But for some reason, blender has cached some animations or force field settings, which I cannot seem to remove from the project.

I have prepared a sample project, removing everything from my actual project but the one Plane with particle settings enabled, and created a new particle set. What you can see is that as soon as you enable "Hair dynamics" in particle settings, between frame 1 and 2 (the only two frames in my project)  there is some kind of offset and movement in the hair being renderred.

I have tried to delete all bakes, save cache to disk, but it did not improve the situation.

When I start a new project from scratch and do the same thing, nothing similar happens, and the hair stays static, as I expect it.

You can download the sample project here:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ikf6e03ryo8lws8/reduced2.blend/file

I have made some screenshots to see what happens. I would like to understand: why this happens, and how I can remove everything cached or baked to a project from previous tries which I have deleted. It seems to me that there is some remainings stored somewhere that I cannot figure out how to delete.

[image: Difference between first and second frame]